# Rename a table in mysql using bash script

Tags: mysql, bash

I just want to rename some tables in the same mysql database using bash script, so I can call it through the cronjob.

The table is in innodb storage,  I can do the same in phpmyadmin in < 1 sec. for rename any table.  Would like to do the same using bash script. it is way faster than copy to a new table with new name.

Just need to get the right synatax for it. I know the db and table name.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

echo "rename table t1 to t2" | mysql ... db

Comment: Hi,
What is that command? php? I want to use bash script to do it.

Comment: This is bash, and can be executed in a script or commandline.

Comment: @JeremyGurr - you're not wrong but it's also not helpful to write a one line answer like this. If you're going to answer questions, please add as best an explanation as you can so that other users coming here later can get a better understanding of what it is doing.